# How to use joins with `where` condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to get users with their assets, which have type 'Google'.

I tried

```rb
User.joins(:assets).where(assets: { assetable_type: 'Google' })
```

or

```rb
User.joins(:assets).where("assets.assetable_type = 'Google'")
```

But that scopes work identically and return nothing.

SQL, which scopes generate:

```sql
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "assets" ON "assets"."assetable_id" = "users"."id" AND "assets"."assetable_type" = 'User' WHERE (assets.assetable_type = 'Google')
```

It doesn't seem to look right

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From what I see you have a polymorphic association defined in Rails.
Can you provide the relations declarations and the SQL that would seem right?

Comment: User.joins('assets.assetable_id = users.id AND assets.assetable_type = "Google"')

Comment: `where` is used to filter rowset of joined records. `joins` designed to join records from few tables by some attributes and you can not specify them in `where` statement, it should be done in `INNER JOIN [TABLE] ON  [ATTRIBUTES]`.

Comment: by default, in rails `User.joins(:assets)` means `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "assets" ON "assets"."assetable_id" = "users"."id" AND "assets"."assetable_type" = 'User'` and u cannot path here any arguments to change join condition. But you can write custom join: `User.joins('assets.assetable_id = users.id AND assets.assetable_type = "Google"')`

Comment: When you have a polymorphic association defined in your Asset model and you run a query for associated records having a specific foreign id but not the expected foreign type then your query doesn't make any sense anymore because you will load records that only by accident share the same id but are not really connected by the defined association (because the type doesn't match). Please show how you defined the associations in the models.

Comment: Your expectation is very strange. Since your Asset model presumably defines `belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true` it means that `assetable_type` points to the model that the `assetable_id` relates to.  `User.joins(:assets)` is correct to generate `INNER JOIN assets ON assets.assetable_id = user.id AND assets.assetable_type = 'User'`. `assetable_type` does not define the type of the asset, it defines the type of the *assetable*. (1/2)

Comment: To define the type of an asset use a separate attribute. For example the `asset_type` attribute. You can then retrieve the users with a Google asset using the query `User.distinct.joins(:assets).where(assets: { asset_type: 'Google' })` which should produce the query `SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN assets ON assets.assetable_id = user.id AND assets.assetable_type = 'User' WHERE assets.asset_type = 'Google'` (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't gave any details about your models and associations

So, I can give you a temporary solution to use raw sql

```
  sql = "SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN assets ON assets.assetable_id = users.id WHERE assets.assetable_type = 'Google'"
  result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
```

Note: If you are using relation as per rails standards it should be

```
  sql = "SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN assets ON assets.assetable_id = users.id WHERE assets.assetable_type = 'Google'"
  result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
```

But I think you are using another name i.e., assetable_id instead of user_id.